# Apply bindings to just the body tag and no descendents

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm looking to apply bindings to the body tag to set a css class based up some subscribed to observable from a viewmodel that is nested within the body tag.

Here is a brief sample of what I'm trying to do. This is actually a jQuery Mobile app, so not sure if that will make a gigantic difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/aPscQ/

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are looking for, but this post might help you out: knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

are you simply wanting to add the text box to the list?

if so

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/3fa6V/

or are you wanting to add to a view model then bind against that?

if so

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/TaDZF/

Comment: Keith, I ended up going with Tyrsius' comment. Ryan N's article was exactly what I was after. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html -- thanks none the less!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with Tyrsius' comment linking to Ryan N's article.. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Thanks!